# CoreData Entity Inheritance

Tags: iphone, inheritance, core-data, entity

Consider that i have two entities with following relationship:

```
Entity A <-->> Entity B (one-to-many and inverse)
```

Now consider that i have another entity Entity C that contains all the attributes of Entity B and some others, with following relationship:

```
Entity A <-->> Entity C (one-to-many and inverse)
```

Now i can improve the architecture by making Entity B the parent of Entity C.

```
Entity B
   ^
   |
Entity C
```

Now, my question is, will the attribute(s) AS WELL AS the relationship(s) be inherited by Entity C? Meaning, do i still need to keep the following relationship (separately)?:

```
Entity A <-->> Entity C
```

Also, i couldn't find a good example for entity inheritance in Apple documentation for Core Data. Does anyone know of an online resource that explains this, with example (preferably)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, attributes and relationships and everything else will be inherited.  Be careful though, child entities like that will share the same table in sqlite with the parent entity.  So if you have C inheriting from B, then a table will be created in sqlite that has the properties for both B and C which the obvious voids in the table.  This is not too much of an issue with a simple inheritance like this but if you decide to get "creative" you can end up with your entire model in one table.

Comment: Are you sure with this? *“Child entities like that will share the same table in sqlite with the parent entity.”* Can you provide some references for that?

Comment: Yes I am positive.  I have tested it, and seeing it on countless occasions.  I am the reference :)

Comment: @Tricertops, what Marus telling is true.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, my question is, will the
>   attribute(s) AS WELL AS the
>   relationship(s) be inherited by Entity
>   C? Meaning, do i still need to keep
>   the following relationship
>   (separately)?:

Yes all attributes and relationships are inherited.
Only little documentation is available at [ADC](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html)

Comment: But, the documentation only refers to "properties" and not "relationships", which is why i posted this question here. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: attributes + relations == properties, so the documentation is right, still it could be a little more helpful.